# Int in string does not change when i change the int value

Tags: java, android

So I'm making a code that uses int value in a string(hardcoded btw), it works but when I incremented the value of the int by button click, the int in the string does not change as the increment.

```
int indexOfQuestion= 1; 
numberOfQuestion.setText("Question " + indexOfQuestion + " from " + lengthOfQuestion + " :" );
switch(v.getId()):
case R.id.next:
indexOfQuestion = indexOfQuestion+1;
```

so when I clicked the button, indexOfQuestion in numberOfQuestion stays 1. How do i change it automatically as I intended without long verbose codes? thanks

Comment: post complete code so that we can see context.

Comment: may be you are assigning int indexOfQuestion = 1 each time.

Comment: Post the complete method

Comment: you have to declare int indexOfQuestion= 1;  globally or set text in your click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it won't change because you setText before you increment int value.
if you want to apply changes, you should setText again after the incrementation.

```
int indexOfQuestion= 1;

numberOfQuestion.setText("Question " + indexOfQuestion + " from " + lengthOfQuestion + " :" );
switch(v.getId()):
case R.id.next: indexOfQuestion = indexOfQuestion+1;
numberOfQuestion.setText("Question " + indexOfQuestion + " from " + lengthOfQuestion + " :" );
```

Comment: Okay, I had in mind of doing this, but I thought it was too verbose than necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

What actually you are doing is calling this statement each time whenever you click the button:

```
 int indexOfQuestion = 1;
```

What you need to do is change the scope of `int indexOfQuestion = 1;` and take it to outside of the method body.

```
public class Test {
     private int indexOfQuestion = 1; 
}
```

Instead of putting it inside `onClick` function.